# Fatal error: Class "PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase" not found

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm following the [documentation of PHPUnit](http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/database.html#database.database-assertions-api); I'm trying the following example; but it keeps giving me the following error:

> "Fatal error: Class "PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase" not found!

It is working fine for `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase`! I also added

```
require_once 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php';
```

but still the same error!

```
<?php
class MyGuestbookTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase
{
    /**
     * @return PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DB_IDatabaseConnection
     */
    public function getConnection()
    {
        $pdo = new PDO('sqlite::memory:');
        return $this->createDefaultDBConnection($pdo, ':memory:');
    }

    /**
     * @return PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DataSet_IDataSet
     */
    public function getDataSet()
    {
        return $this->createFlatXMLDataSet(dirname(__FILE__).'/_files/guestbook-seed.xml');
    }
}
?>
```

Updated:

Actually I'm very new to PHPUnit test:

I used Slim framework of PHP: I have not started testing; just trying to understand the logic by going through the documentation; I do have a composer.json file which is the following: (now I added "phpunit/dbunit": ">=1.2" in require / require-dev, but none of them solved the problem!):

```
{
    "name": "slim/slim",
    "type": "library",
    "description": "Slim Framework, a PHP micro framework",
    "keywords": ["microframework","rest","router"],
    "homepage": "http://github.com/codeguy/Slim",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Josh Lockhart",
            "email": "info@joshlockhart.com",
            "homepage": "http://www.joshlockhart.com/"
        }
    ],
    "require": {        
        "php": ">=5.3.0"
    }
    ,"require-dev": {        
        "phpunit/dbunit": ">=1.2"
    },
    "suggest": {
        "ext-mcrypt": "Required for HTTP cookie encryption"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "Slim": "." }
    }
}
```

If you need more clarification, please let me know and thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm curious about the lowercase "d" in "database" in your error message. Are you sure you've spelt the class name correctly?

Comment: Yes! I just did not copy & paste correctly here! I corrected it here! I spelled it correctly and thanks for editing!

Comment: Have you included the `DBUnit` [optional package](http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html#installation.optional-packages) in your composer file (assuming you're using composer)?

Comment: I do have a composer.json file which now I added in my updated question now I added "phpunit/dbunit": ">=1.2" in require and require-dev, but none of them solved the problem!

Comment: Should I hard-code it in the way that I did now?

Comment: Did you run `composer install`?

Comment: I had this problem too. Here is my take on the issue. Path of autoload.php  might create a problem. It depends on the installation of composer. I'd recommend you check inside the composer. From there you can provide path for vendor/autoload.php. Composer can be a hidden folder. So you'll have to look for it.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Composer, make sure you add the [DBUnit](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html#installation.optional-packages) optional package.

All credit goes to Phil's comment!

Comment: I'm getting a warning about  PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase on one of my projects. I tried adding DBUnit with the `composer require --dev phpunit/dbunit` command, but I'm getting an error because I'm not using phpunit 6.0. Why exactly did I need to include this in my project? Apparently something I'm doing is triggering it. This particular project does have database access, but I don't have tests on database access yet.

Comment: Jay, you probably need to install a version of DBUnit compatible with your version of PHPUnit. For instance, I am using PHPUnit `v5.7` so I needed to install DBUnit `v2.0.3`: `composer require --dev phpunit/dbunit:2.0.3`. [Source](https://packagist.org/packages/phpunit/dbunit#2.0.3)